# Get the default PropertyDescriptors for a type

Tags: c#, propertygrid, propertyinfo, propertydescriptor

I'm customizing how an object type is displayed in a `PropertyGrid` by implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. I'm allowing the user to create their own custom properties that are stored in a single dictionary of keys and values. I'm able to create all the `PropertyDescriptors` for these values and view them in the property grid. However, I also want to show all the default properties that otherwise would have shown if the `PropertyGrid` was populated through reflection rather than my override `ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties` method.

Now I know how to get the type of the object, and then `GetProperties()`, but this returns an array of `PropertyInfo` not `ProperyDescriptor`. So how can I convert the `PropertyInfo` object of the type into `PropertyDescriptor` objects to include into my collection with the custom `PropertyDescriptors`?

```
//gets the local intrinsic properties of the object
Type thisType = this.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] thisProps = thisType.GetProperties();

//this line obviously doesn't work because the propertydescriptor 
//collection needs an array of PropertyDescriptors not PropertyInfo
PropertyDescriptorCollection propCOl = 
    new PropertyDescriptorCollection(thisProps);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(thisType);
```

As an aside: this won't include your `ICustomTypeDescriptor` customisations, but it *will* include any customisations made via `TypeDescriptionProvider`.

(edit)
As a second aside - you can also tweak `PropertyGrid` by providing a `TypeConverter` - much simpler than either `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProvider` - for example:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
class Foo { }

class FooConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(
       ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        // your code here, perhaps using base.GetPoperties(
        //    context, value, attributes);
    }
}
```